# A global version of evil C-w

Tags: evil

In vim and evil mode, normal-state `C-w` prefixes various window-related
commands.  For example, `C-w l` moves focus to the right, and `C-w L`
moves the currently focused window to the right.

I would like access these commands in buffers that do not play well with
evil mode (such as PDF buffers).  Is it possible to make `C-c w` act
globally as `C-w` does in evil normal state?  It should be possible to
use prefixes and counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is assign your keybinding of choice to
`evil-window-map`, whose docstring is:

> Prefix command (definition is a keymap associating keystrokes with commands).

In your case, the following should work:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-c w") #'evil-window-map)
```